# How to populate the listview?

Tags: android, listview, network-programming

```
 public void Connect(final String ip, final int port, final String Data)       throws IOException {

    Thread t = new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                s = new Socket(ip, port);
                dos  = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                dos.write(stringToBytesASCII(Data),0,Data.length());
                dos.flush();

                byte[] buff = new byte[dis.available()];
                dis.read(buff,0,buff.length);
                address = AsciiToString(buff);
                addresslist.add(address);
                ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row_layout, addresslist);
                lstMicAdd.setAdapter(myAdapter);


            } catch ( IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


    };
    t.start();
```

when i get the Data[] from the DataInputStream, ive placed it in a Arraylist. but when i run it, it keeps on stopping after it gets the stream . what is wrong with my code ? or how im gonna do it? please help

heres my logcat

04-03 10:57:20.362    1980-1995/www.siren.com.siren D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true

04-03 10:57:20.386    1980-1980/www.siren.com.siren D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae138ee0, tid 1980

04-03 10:57:20.415    1980-1980/www.siren.com.siren D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...

04-03 10:57:20.460    1980-1995/www.siren.com.siren D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c8d460, tid 1995

04-03 10:57:20.500    1980-1995/www.siren.com.siren I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4

04-03 10:57:20.700    1980-1995/www.siren.com.siren D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0

04-03 10:57:20.747    1980-1995/www.siren.com.siren W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

04-03 10:57:20.747    1980-1995/www.siren.com.siren W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c8e220, error=EGL_SUCCESS

04-03 10:57:22.217    1980-1980/www.siren.com.siren I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 81 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

04-03 10:57:22.736    1980-1992/www.siren.com.siren I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2473(121KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 9% free, 18MB/20MB, paused 1.616ms total 181.248ms

04-03 10:57:22.812    1980-1995/www.siren.com.siren W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

04-03 10:57:22.812    1980-1995/www.siren.com.siren W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6cb5de0, error=EGL_SUCCESS

04-03 10:57:24.224    1980-1980/www.siren.com.siren I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 80 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

04-03 11:00:10.990    1980-1995/www.siren.com.siren W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

04-03 11:00:10.990    1980-1995/www.siren.com.siren W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6cb5de0, error=EGL_SUCCESS

04-03 11:02:27.930    1980-1980/www.siren.com.siren I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

04-03 11:03:12.926    1980-1980/www.siren.com.siren I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-03 11:03:13.725    1980-1995/www.siren.com.siren W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

04-03 11:03:13.725    1980-1995/www.siren.com.siren W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c8eb80, error=EGL_SUCCESS

04-03 11:03:15.416    1980-1980/www.siren.com.siren I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 148 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

04-03 11:03:17.634    1980-1980/www.siren.com.siren I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 132 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

here's my whole code

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_ONE = 100;
private Button btnConnect;
private Button btnSettings;
private Button btnDisc;
private ListView lstMicAdd;
private Socket s;
private DataOutputStream dos;
private DataInputStream dis;
String address;
DatabaseHandled dbHandler;
String settingsIp;
protected int settingsPort;
String Name;
List<String> addresslist = new ArrayList<String>();


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    btnConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);
    btnSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSettings);
    btnDisc = (Button) findViewById((R.id.btnDisc));
    dbHandler = new DatabaseHandled(getApplicationContext());
    Name = dbHandler.getLastNameRecord();
    settingsIp = dbHandler.getLastIprecord();
    settingsPort = Integer.parseInt(dbHandler.getLastPortRecord());
    btnDisc.setEnabled(false);
    lstMicAdd = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstMicAdd);


    //Settings Button
    btnSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this , settings.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ONE);
        }
    });


    //Connect Button
    btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                Connect(settingsIp, settingsPort, "Android_" + Name);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }





        }
    });


    //Disconnect Button
    btnDisc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                s.close();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    });



}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_ONE){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                settingsPort = data.getIntExtra("Port",-1);
                settingsIp = data.getStringExtra("Ip-Address");

        }
     }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

public void Connect(final String ip, final int port, final String Data) throws IOException {

    Thread t = new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                s = new Socket(ip, port);
                dos  = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                dos.write(stringToBytesASCII(Data),0,Data.length());
                dos.flush();

                byte[] buff = new byte[dis.available()];
                dis.read(buff,0,buff.length);
                address = AsciiToString(buff);
                addresslist.add(address);



            } catch ( IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row_layout, addresslist);
            lstMicAdd.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        }


    };
    t.start();


}







    public static byte[] stringToBytesASCII(String Data) {

        byte[] b = new byte[Data.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {

            b[i] = (byte) Data.charAt(i);
        }
        return b;

    }

public static String AsciiToString(byte[] Data) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Data.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < Data.length; ++ i) {
        if (Data[i] < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        sb.append((char) Data[i]);
    }
    return sb.toString();


}

public void Alert (){
    AlertDialog myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    myDialog.setTitle("Error");
    myDialog.setMessage("No Connection");
    myDialog.show();


}
```

}

Comment: thats also my problem, theres no error on may logcat after my app stopped. im alway relying on my logcat when there is a problem . but now theres none, no error on my logcat -_-

Comment: PLEASE HELP . I REALLY NEED YOUR HELP GUYS :(

Comment: There is nothing to go off of.... Post your logcat and then i can help.

Comment: have you verified that your address is not null here "addresslist.add(address);" ?

Comment: yes is not null , after addresslist.add(address), the size of the addresslist is 1. so it add the address ..

Comment: show complete code with layout

Comment: when i connect to the server, the server will send a bunch of addresses e.g (peoples ave, some Street, etc) , and i want my app to put in in the listview,